# How have a string and an int tied together. Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

the program is a version of d&d I'm writing for fun. In the character creation, I need to have skills that has an int and string and the int should be able to be added and subtracted from. but the string should be the same. I thought of doing a 2d array but that was a bad idea because object 2d array are just bad so now can't think of anything else.

Comment: Java is an object oriented language. You define classes and create objects. These objects hold information as fields. Like for example, a String field and an int field.

Comment: You could put the integers in a map keyed by string.Map<String, Integer>

Answer (score 0):

declare a class with two fields in it 1.int and 2.String

```
class A
{
    int i;
    String s;
}
```

in the main method create array object (of class A) of that class you can access int and String by dot(.) method

like :

```
A[] obj = new A[10];//creating array of object
```

now access all elements by :

```
for(int j=0;i<obj.length;j++)
{
obj[j]=new A();//assigning object to reference
obj[j].i=10;
obj[j].s="hello";
}
```

Comment: Why new obj() ? Do you mean new A()?

Comment: Oh yeah.. sorry..!